# The_content only for article site?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am developing a wordpress plugin. I got my variables and I set my html in my function. Thats my action I added:

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'test' );
```

But my html is displayed on the article overview site too. I just want my action being called on an article site. So how is the hook called or how could I manage it to get it working?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to use

```
if(is_single())
```

to check if the site is an article detail site and not the overview site.